# Por que a função "table" não mostra a contagem dos valores perdidos "NA" em uma variável?

Tags: r

A seguinte variável apresenta dois valores perdidos ("NA")

```
table(is.na(titanic.sobreviventes$Embarked))
```

```
FALSE  1307    
TRUE  2
```

```
table(titanic.sobreviventes$Embarked)
```

Porém, as observações perdidas "NA" não são mostradas no resultado do seguinte código:

```
  C 270 
  Q 123 
  S 914
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(titanic)
```

```
titanic_train2 <- rbind(titanic_train, NA)
```

```
table(is.na(titanic_train2$Sex))
```

```
FALSE  TRUE 
  891     1
```

Você pode usar o agumento "useNA" com a opção "ifany" para visualizar "NA"
na função `table()`

```
table(titanic_train2$Sex, useNA = "ifany")
```

```
female   male   <NA> 
   314    577      1
```

Comment: titanic.sobreviventes[titanic.sobreviventes$Embarked == '', "Embarked"] <- 's'     Esta linha de comando não esta indo  a substituição do NA não entra o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Oi Renata augusto! Você poderia, por favor, editar a sua pergunta (ou abrir uma nova) para focar na dúvida principal e para fazer ela reproduzível? Como estava formulada anteriormente parecia ter duas dúvidas e o assunto principal estava relacionado com a função `table()`, porém, parece que a sua dúvida é sobre como sustituir valores perdidos com um caracter. Tenho certeza que terá boas respostas se você formular a sua pergunta de maneira que seja reproduzível e específica. Veja este link sobre o assunto: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Se você precisa sustituir valores perdidos por um caractere pode usar R base. Primeiro, criando um vector que indexa os valores perdidos como "TRUE" usando esse código: `miss <- is.na(titanic_train2$Sex)`; depois pode usar esse vector para selecionar observações que são "NA" e pode sustituí-las indexando com o operador `<-` usando um código similar a esse:  `titanic_train2[miss, "Sex"] <- "Other"`. É isso o que você está precisando fazer?

Comment: Muito Obrigada, era isso mesmo.